# How to properly truncate an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space for quantum optics simulations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-optics, regularization

In order to solve numerically a master equation in which the Hamiltonian and the jump operators are defined in terms of the infinite-dimensional annihilation and creation operators, we have to truncate them to some finite size $N$. The question is then how do we determine the $N$ so that the results are good to some approximation. One idea that comes to my mind is to compare the $N$ with the quantity $R=\langle n \rangle + Var(n)/2$ of the computed state for this $N$, and increase $N$ until $R-N>\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon$. Is it a good way to choose a truncation?

Comment: What's wrong with "increase $N$ until your calculations converge"?

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty, what do you mean converge? The computation gives a density matrix.

Comment: In the standard usage of the term, it means: until the physical predictions of the calculation no longer change with your truncation limit.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty, yes that is a possible approach, but not a very practical one? It requires repeating the computation many times until you stop seeing a big change in the density matrix elements.

Comment: Indeed it does - welcome to computational physics =)! For sure, if you have a good idea of how big $N$ needs to be then it will still speed up the process (and *how* you get that guess is a good question, but at present there's not a lot of information in your post), but you will always need to check with a bigger $N$ to make sure that it is converged. If you don't do a convergence test, you're liable to be reporting truncation effects as if they were real physics, which is not a situation you want to be in.